# Programa que verifique si un correo electronico escrito por teclado es valido JAVA!

Tags: java

Como puedo verificar si un string tecleado es un correo. Es decir si tiene el @ y el punto. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola @Jossiel, Cuéntanos ¿Qué intentaste? , recomiendo dar un vistazo al [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Amigo, copia tu código aqui para poder ayudarte!!

Answer (score 6):

> la solucion que encuentro mas rapida es la siguiente, (propongo la
>   solución bajo el supuesto que has trabajado con expresiones
>   regulares).

1.- Para verificar la estructura de un correo, sólo con caracteres válidos, se empieza por importar las clases de Java habituales para manejo de expresiones regulares.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

2.- Posteriormente, se define el patrón que especifica una dirección de email válida.

```
String emailPattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@" +
  "[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$";
```

la expresion regular me parece bastante clara sin embargo agregaré la descripcion:

^ especifica el inicio de la entrada.

([_a-z0-9-]) primer grupo. Se refiere a la aparición de uno o más caracteres compuestos por guión bajo, letras, números y guiones.

(\.[_a-z0-9-]) segundo grupo. Puede ser opcional y repetible, se refiere a la aparición de un punto seguido de uno o más caracteres compuestos por guión bajo, letras, números y guiones.

*@ carácter arroba.

([a-z0-9-]) tercer grupo. Especifica la aparición de uno o más caracteres compuestos por letras, números y guiones.

(\.[a-z0-9-]) cuarto grupo. Especifica un punto seguido de uno o más caracteres compuestos por letras, números y guiones.

(\.[a-z]{2,4}) quinto grupo. Especifica un punto seguido de entre 2 y 4 letras, con el fin de considerar dominios terminados, por ejemplo, en .com y .info (puedes modificar el numero de caracteres segun tus necesidades).

$ especifica el fin de la entrada.

3.- Compilamos la expresión regular

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
```

4.- puedes guardar el valor obtenido desde teclado en la variable email por ejemplo, En caso de que el email no sea nulo, se le aplica el patrón y se comprueba si cumple con este o no para este ejemplo se mostrara en consola el mensaje "Valido"

```
   if (email != null) {
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
     if (matcher.matches()) {
       System.out.println("Válido");
   }
```

5.- De no haber sido válido el email, simplemente se muestra el mensaje NO Válido.

```
else {
     System.out.println("NO Válido");
   }
```

y de esa forma puedes verificar si un correo es valido aqui dejare el codigo de ejemplo completo. espero haber podido ayudarte.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmailValid {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email  = input.nextLine();
    String emailPattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@" +
      "[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(emailPattern);
      if (email != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          System.out.println("Valido");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("NO Valido");
        }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: ok, de acuerdo creo que ire a leer las reglas, soy nuevo respondiendo.

Comment: Te lo agradezco Gerardo, me ha sido muy util. Mil gracias por la explicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con un contains. Si la cadena que recibes contiene el @ y además contiene extensiones comunes como .com .es .org .eu y demás, lo das por válido.

Ejemplo:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String emailIntroducido;
emailIntroducido = input.nextLine();

if (emailIntroducido.contains("@") && (emailIntroducido.contains(".com") || emailIntroducido.contains(".es")))    {

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Aldruxx